# PHP function as argument in if statement (Object Oriented)

Tags: php, mysql, oop

when I run this:

```
if ($result->num_rows() > 0) {                                    
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {                     
            echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br>";   
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

I get the following error:

> Call to undefined method mysqli_result::num_rows()

I presume the error is from the `num_rows()` method but can't quite figure out what is wrong. As far as I know, objects call methods by using `$obj->foo()` in OOP but when I remove the parenthesis of `num_row`:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {                                    
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {                     
            echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br>";   
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

this block of code runs as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the second block of code works is because `num_rows` is an attribute of the object.  Using `num_rows()` as a method results in a undefined method error because there is no method by that name.

An example:

```
class Dog {
    public weight;
    public age;

    public function __construct($weight, $age)
    {
        $this->weight = $weight;
        $this->age = $age;
    }

    public function bark()
    {
       ...
    }

    public function gain_weight()
    {
       $this->weight++;
    }
}

$dog = new Dog(10, 0);
$dog->gain_weight();
echo $dog->weight;
```

`gain_weight` is a method, but `weight` is an attribute of the `$dog` object.

On a side note, `if ($result->num_rows > 0)` is the same as `if ($result->num_rows)` since if `$result->num_rows` equals 0, the statement will evaluate to false.

Comment: Ok great. So `num_rows` is a attribute created by php already and not a method?

Comment: Yes.  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php and for the entire class http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php

Comment: You can see that `$num_rows` is defined as an attribute (aka property, member variable, etc).

Comment: Do you have any further questions?

Comment: you're amazing! Meanwhile I don't know what is wrong with stackoverflow and down rating questions. It discourages learning! Great one man